# Photoshop transform selection on a single layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I am not a photoshop expert, but have used it quite a bit over the years. I thought what I am about to describe below was a doable task using `select` and `transform selection`

So here is the problem.....

I have a multilayered PSD file. I just increased the canvas size by 30px to the right. Then I `selected` the bottom layer which is a blue gradient graphic meant for the background of the image. Then I selected the right side of the bottom layer just described.

Next I clicked on `select` and picked `Transform Selection`. Then I pulled the `Transform selection` to the right to stretch blue gradient into the empty canvas I created, but it does not pull anything but empty pixels.

Am I doing something wrong? I could have sworn I did this with CS3, but I just got CC and I noticed the settings are a little different in some places, but not much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform Selection is designed to transform the **selection area** and **not** the pixels within it. You want to use `Edit > Free Transform` and **not** `Select > Transform Selection`.

In short... Transform Selection changes the marching ants themselves. Free Transform changes what is inside the marching ants.

Comment: So the only way to pick part of the layer to stretch is to create a new PSD, drag layer there and then stretch it. Then drag the layer back?

Comment: No. Do as I posted. Create a selection, highlight a layer in the Layers Panel, then use Edit > Free Transform, you will transform what is selected. You are simply picking the *wrong menu item*. This assume the layer you are altering is a pixel-based layer. Altering only a portion of a layer in this fashion is not supported with vector-based layers.

Comment: Ok Sorry misread that, its works!